# WooCommerce - Retrieving the correct data value for select box after submitting

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, html-select

I am using Woocommerce and I have built a select box in the Admin Panel. I populate the information in the select box via a flat file. 
Everything works fine (almost).

The part I am stuck on is after I select the "choice" I want and the save I am getting the array **`$key`** position and not the actual **`$value`**. I'm close but I just can't put my finger on it.

Update: Here is my full code:

```
function woo_add_custom_admin_product_tab() {
?>
    <li class="custom_tab"><a href="#custom_tab_data"><?php _e('Additional Information', 'woocommerce'); ?></a></li>
<?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs', 'woo_add_custom_admin_product_tab' );


function woo_add_custom_admin_fields() {    
    global $woocommerce, $post;

    echo '<div id="custom_tab_data" class="panel woocommerce_options_panel">';
    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    // Select - Breed1
    if (file_exists ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) .'breed.txt')) {
        $breedData = file_get_contents ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) .'breed.txt');
        $breedArray = explode ("\n", $breedData);
    }

    woocommerce_wp_select(array(
        'id'      => '_select_breed1',
        'label'   => __( 'Select Primary Breed', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Select the primary breed of the pet.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'options' => $breedArray
    ) );
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_write_panels', 'woo_add_custom_admin_fields' );


// Save Fields;
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
    // Text Field - Pet Name
    $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_pet_name'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
       update_post_meta( $post_id, '_pet_name', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );

    // Select Field - Breed
    $woocommerce_select = $_POST['_select_breed1'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_select ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_select_breed1', esc_attr( $woocommerce_select ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
```

My breed.txt file contains 3 lines (items):

```css
Please Select a breed...
Abyssinian
Affenpinscher
```

And the generated array looks like this:

```css
Array ( 
    [0] => Please Select a breed... 
    [1] => Abyssinian 
    [2] => Affenpinscher 
)
```

So when I select **`"Affenpinscher"`** for example, I get as value **`"2"`** instead of  **`"Affenpinscher"`** .

What I am doing wrong? How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Your array has nothing to do with a flat file, consider renaming this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

— Updated — *(tested and working)*

This is absolutely a normal behavior for a drop down selector **`<select>`**. You just need to add some little things in your code to make it work in a different way.

> **The changes are**: 
>   — first, when the array of values from the external text file is available, I store it in wordpress options. 
>   — Second, In the last saving function, I get the stored array and with the selected **`key`** that I get from **`$_POST['_select_breed_key1'];`**, I retrieve the corresponding value that I store in a new entry (new row in wp_postmeta table.

```
//Create the fields
function woo_add_custom_admin_fields() {    
    global $woocommerce, $post;

    echo '<div id="custom_tab_data" class="panel woocommerce_options_panel">';
    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    // Select - Breed1
    if (file_exists ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) .'breed.txt')) {
        $breedData = file_get_contents ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) .'breed.txt');
        $breedArray = explode ("\n", $breedData);

        //Storing the array in wp_options table
        if( get_option( 'wc_product_add_info_tab' ) )
            update_option( 'wc_product_add_info_tab', $breedArray );
        else
            add_option( 'wc_product_add_info_tab', $breedArray );
    }

    woocommerce_wp_select( array(
        'id'      => '_select_breed_key1',
        'label'   => __( 'Select Primary Breed', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Select the primary breed of the pet.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'options' => $breedArray
    ) );

    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_write_panels', 'woo_add_custom_admin_fields' );


// Save Created Fields;
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

    // Select Field - Breed
    $wc_select = $_POST['_select_breed_key1'];
    if( !empty( $wc_select ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_select_breed_key1', esc_attr( $wc_select ) );

    // Saving the corresponding value (from "$wc_select" selected key) to database
    if(get_option('wc_product_add_info_tab')) {

        // Getting the array
        $breed_arr = get_option('wc_product_add_info_tab');

        // Saving the corresponding value
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_select_breed_value1', $breed_arr[$wc_select] );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
```

> You have now in in **`wp_postmeta`** table for a Product ID (post_id), 2 meta_keys:
>   - **`'_select_breed_key1'`** that stores the selected key
>   - **`'_select_breed_value1'`** that stores the corresponding value

Usage for example (to get this value):

```
<?php

// Third parameter is set to "true" as it is a string (Not an array) 
$breed_value1 = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_select_breed_value1', true );
echo $breed_value1;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Loic!

It looks like I was heading in the right direction and I needed to get the [$value] of the array.

Unfortunately its not working like I would expect it to. When I click the update the value is not getting saved to the database. Just an FYI, I am also using functions to accomplish this, here is my complete code:

Comment: Woo Hoo! It worked! Just one correction I had to do...

In the // Select Field - Breed section I just had to update the:
if( !empty( $woocommerce_select ) )
to be
if( !empty( $wc_select ) )

But otherwise it worked!

I still have to learn the array and select box characteristics.

But thanks, it worked....

I think I am going to attempt pulling from the Database next!

Comment: Oh yes sorry… when renaming forgot this one. updated.